# Use JQuery each function to return element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have an `ul` with around 20 `li`. Each `li` is structured like this:

```
 <li class="block">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="back">
     <p>Text</p>
    </div>  
  </a>
</li>
```

I would like to go through each `li.block`, find its width, and set the anchor tag's width equal to this number.

This is the function I'm using now, but it isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $currentWidth = $("li.block").width();
  $( "li.block a" ).css( "width", $currentWidth);
});
```

What is the proper way to use `.each()` and something similar to the code above to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle through every block use

```
$("li.block").each(function() {//stuff});
```

Inside that function you can get the relevant block with `this`:

```
var width = $(this).width();
```

You can then apply that to the link inside that block:

```
$(this).children('a').css("width", $currentWidth);
```

Of course, that might be a little different if your html wasn't always like that - use whatever selector is appropriate.

So putting it all together, you would have something like this:

```
$("li.block").each(funtion() {
  var width = $(this).width();
  $(this).children('a').css("width", $currentWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('#your-ul').find('li.block').each(function(){
  // inside here, 'this' refers to to a specific 'li.block' element
  $(this).find('a').width( $(this).width() );
});
```

although I am a bit suspicious about why these aren't already the same width.

Comment: I'm guessing that op has list elements displayed as block, and is trying to make the entire thing a link.  in which case, why not just put the anchor tag around the li